# What is the max numeric value that can be stored on firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a system that will eventually store extremely large number values (double or floating point types, not int) and I'm using firestore to store my data. Is there a cap for how big numbers can grow in a firestore database? I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types), Firestore allows only 64 bit signed integers. A 64-bit signed integer. It has a `minimum value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a maximum value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive)`.

Same for float: Firestore allows [64-bit double precision, IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

I just tried adding a random number over that limit and you get.

[image]

Then I tried requesting the document and that's the data you get:
[image]

It'll be hard to get the precise value if you store it as a number. You may be interested storing the number in string format if that numbers are that large. But do keep the 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes) limit of a document in mind.

Comment: Thanks for finding that! It looks like their 64 bit float data type has single digit accuracy up until −9,007,199,254,740,992 or 9,007,199,254,740,992 according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) and it gets less precise the farther from that you go.

Comment: @BrianChristensen yes that's correct. If your numbers are even large and precision is important, then it'll make sense to use a string in Firestore.